# Trouble with basic Buoyancy : a treasure chest on a raft

Tags: homework-and-exercises, buoyancy

I'm having trouble sorting through the following problem:

> You are shipwrecked and floating in the middle of the ocean on a raft. Your cargo on the raft includes a treasure chest full of gold that you found before your ship sank, and the raft is just barely afloat. To keep you floating as high as possible in the water, should you (a) leave the treasure chest on top of the raft, (b) secure the treasure chest to the underside of the raft, or (c) hang the treasure chest in the water with a rope attached to the raft? (Assume throw- ing the treasure chest overboard is not an option you wish to consider.)

It's easy enough for me to see why (c) should be a good solution given the following identity:

$
{\Huge \frac{V_{displaced}}{V_{object}}\ =\ \frac{\rho_{object}}{\rho_{fluid}}}
$

The density of the raft and chest together is greater than the density of each object alone. So, the numerator of the right-hand side of the identity would go down, and so necessarily would the left. The chest doesn't contribute much to the volume of the raft, so the volume displaced would have to go down.

However, the back of the book says (b) is also a viable solution.

Why?

Comment: Without given values, '_The density of the raft and chest together is greater than the density of each object alone_' is not necessarily a true statement. The density of both together is (Assuming the chest is fully inside the raft) $\frac{\rho_1 V_1 + \rho_2 V_2}{V_1} = \rho_1 + \rho_2 \frac{V_2}{V_1} = \rho_{total}$. It's totally possible to have $\rho_{total} < \rho_2$ with a small enough $\rho_1$ or $V_2$, or large enough $V_1$.

Comment: True. But this question, as worded, is meant to imply that the chest has relatively a lot of mass in a relatively small volume, as compared to the raft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Securing the treasure chest to the underside of the raft will mean that less volume of the raft is required to stay afloat.

Assume your raft is a cuboid with bottom of area $A$ (for sake of clarity of the maths).

$M_{tot} = M_{raft} + M_{chest} + M_{person}$

Initially, this is held up by a volume of the raft (and none of the chest as the chest is inside)

$M_{tot} = A h_0\rho_{water} $

Where $h_0$ is how much of the height of the boat is in water.

Placing the chest on the underside of the raft, you're increasing the effective volume of the raft.

$M_{tot} = (V_{chest} + A h_1)\cdot \rho_{water}$.

As $V_{chest} > 0$, $h_1 < h_0$, and so you're less in the water than before.

Comment: Thank you! Is this equation from your answer correct? Mtot = A h0 ρwater Should it be something like V object ρ object = A h0 ρwater ? Ah... wait. Mtot  = V object ρ object. Got it.

Comment: The principle of floatation: Weight displaced = Weight of body. The weight of our body is $M_{tot} g$. The weight displaced is $V_{raft} \rho_{water} g$. I chose a cuboid for a raft so we could write $V_{raft} = A h_0$

Comment: This statement: "Placing the chest on the underside of the raft, you're increasing the effective volume of the raft." Would it be more accurate to say "Placing the chest on the underside of the raft, you're increasing the effective volume of the water displaced by the raft"?

Comment: Well the volume of water displaced is always going to be the same, as we have to have the same amount of water displaced for equal buoyancy. My statement isn't worded very well.